# Better way of organizing class module code in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

This is a somewhat imprecise question so happy to get pointers if this is not the right place.

This is the code for my class now :

```py
class theClass:
    def __init__(self):
        # intialization steps

    def action1(self, **kwargs):
        return self.__action("action1", **kwargs)

    def action2(self, **kwargs):
        return self.__action("action2", **kwargs)

    def __action(self, action,**kwargs):

        #some common code

        if action == "action1":
            #some code specific to action1
        elif action == "action2":
            #some code specific to action1
        else:
            raise NotImplementedError(f"Action {action} does not exist.")
```

I have created the `action1` and `action2` function so I can call them directly without going through `__action`. But `#some commmon code` needs to happen before all the specific codes within the actions functions.

Is this an acceptable construction ?

Comment: Seems weird that you put *"code specific to action1"* in the generic `__action` method. Why not put that code into the very function it is specific to?

Comment: `#some common code` happens for all the `action` params in `__action`

Comment: and it needs to happen before the `specific` one

Comment: create `def some_common_code(...)` and run it in `action1()` and `action2()`

Comment: Could you please explain why that is a better construction ? Cleanliness ? Speed ? Convention ?

Comment: Unrelated but 1/ class names should be CamelCase (unless you have a very clear reason to do otherwise) and 2/ the double-leading-underscore name scheme is actually very very seldom used - the convention for "implementation" variables / functions / attributes etc is one single leading underscore.

Comment: for me `def some_common_code(...)` is more readable then long `if/else`.  And it keeps specific code inside `action1()`, `action2()`. But frankly, if you like your version then use it.

Comment: @furas I agree with you and I've made the changes but was wondering if there was an efficiency gain on top of the readability.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers noted about __ and in my actual code the name is CamelCase

Comment: @Chapo wrt/ "efficiency" (assuming you mean "execution time optimization" ), each function call has a fixed cost by itself, and each method invocation adds the resolution overhead + the invocation of the descriptor protocol to get the "method" wrapper for the function + the call of the "method" object. IOW the less indirecttion levels the better; as usual. But if you really have to care about such issues Python might not be the right language for the task, so better to focus on readability and maintainabilty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a decorator:

```
def run_with_common_code(func):
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._common_code(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

class TheClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self._foo = 42

    def _common_code(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("common code: {}, {}, {}".format(self, args, kwargs))


    @run_with_common_code
    def action1(self, arg1, arg2=None):
        #some code specific to action1
        print("action1 with {} and {}".format(arg1, arg2))


    @run_with_common_code
    def action2(self, arg, **kwargs):
        #some code specific to action2
        print("action2 with {} and {}".format(arg, kwargs))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    obj = TheClass()
    obj.action1("foo", "bar")
    obj.action2("baaz", parrot="dead")
```

Now whether it really makes the code clearer is a matter of context and personnal judgement.

As far as I'm concerned, unless I have dozens of "action" to handle - in which case I'd start by rethinking the whole design -, I'd go for the simplest and most obvious solution: wrapping the "common code" in a method and explicitely calling if from "action" methods. It's simple, clear, effective, and gives you more freedom if you later find out you actually have a bit of specific code to call *before* the common code part (which often happens as a result of a requirements change).

Something you learn from experience is that premature generalization is another source of evil ;-)

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I have indeed gone the way of @furas but your answer gave me some stuff to read on and learn !